# Internet Peering Locations

Tags: global, internet

Is there any dataset about worldwide Internet Interconnection locations?

Some information about the average or maximum switching capacity would be nice.

I found a map (and raw data) about seacables (http://www.cablemap.info/), but nothing about connections on land.

Comment: updated that gist. sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any open solution but here's some real quick data I found after a brief search:

[PCH (Packet Clearing House) Internet Exchange Directory](https://www.pch.net/ixp/dir) exposes their data in JSON/TopoJSON here:
[Countries TopoJSON](https://www.pch.net/assets/data/countries.topo.json)
[Directory Data JSON](https://www.pch.net/ixp/dir_data)
and [Data Center Map's Internet Exchange Points (IXPs) map](http://www.datacentermap.com/ixps.html) exposes their data in [one of their JS files](http://www.datacentermap.com/map/ixps.js).

I've put them all into [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jalbertbowden/81a7e3fca4cb4f71af1270d09f0629e1) for the moment. Will probably port to GitHub/Datahub.io/data.world at some point...